# Unity - Slider + Поворот объекта

Tags: unity3d

Добрейшего.
Задача двигать объект по слайдеру, где значение слайдера 0,5 выставляет   объекту 0 градусов по оси z,а значение слайдера в 0 означает поворот на 180 градусов налево,а значение слайдера 1 будет означать поворот направо на 180.Спасибо

Comment: Привет. Отличная задача, можешь начинать делать. Пожалуйста

Comment: Боже мой,спасибо, что разрешил

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Возможно я где то напутал но ка я понял вам надо что бы объект вращался в соответствии со значением слайдера. Так как вы не упомянули 2д проект это или 3д, я делал всё в 2д.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class sliderturner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;
    void Start()
    {
    slider.value = 0.5f;// ставим что бы сладйер изначально по середине был
    }


void Update()
{
    Vector3 newRotate = new Vector3(0,0, (180/100)*(slider.value * -360));//тут вся суть кода если не понятно лучше переспроси что бы на будущее знал
    transform.eulerAngles = newRotate;
}
```

}